# SignalR 2 long polling "protocol" request times out when not ran locally

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

Currently I have an app that is very chatty and needs to be supported by a Singleton(See Code below). I upgraded to SignalR 2.0 and I followed the upgrade guide, but after I deploy it out to an environment, sometimes all requests for every "protocol" fail, and signalr breaks, and when it doesn't break then it is terribly slow to push notifications down to the client from the server, Maybe this has something to do with it using long polling? Here is what my server side code looks like.

Configuration Method in Owin Start up class

```
 var hubConfig = new HubConfiguration();
 hubConfig.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
 GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
 app.MapSignalR(hubConfig);
```

As you can see I am using an SQL Backplane. Here is what my Hub looks like

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public void JoinGroup(int someId)
    {
        Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, someId.ToString());
    }

    public void LeaveGroup(int someId)
    {
        Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, someId.ToString());
    }
}
```

Another point to make here is that I am using groups. Which may be part of the problem, I have noticed that groups seem to make things go slower, as if signalr is waiting for all users from the group to finish after it pushes out a notification. My Singleton looks like this.

```
public class Broadcaster
    {
        private readonly static Lazy<Broadcaster> _instance =
            new Lazy<Broadcaster>(() => new Broadcaster(GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>().Clients));
        private IHubConnectionContext _context;
        private Broadcaster(IHubConnectionContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public static Broadcaster Instance
        {
            get { return _instance.Value; }
        }
        public void UpdateClient(int someId, int moreInfo)
        {
            _context.Group(someId.ToString()).Update(someId, moreInfo);
        }
    }
```

Finally these are the outputs from the logs on the client.

- 16:37:25 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)] SignalR: Client subscribed
  to hub 'myhub'. 16:37:25 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)] SignalR:
  Negotiating with
  '/api/signalr/negotiate?connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22myhub%22%7D%5D&clientProtocol=1.3'.
- then it attempts to connect to an SSE Endpoint and that fails...
- 16:37:30 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)] SignalR: This browser
  supports SSE, skipping Forever Frame.
- 16:37:31 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)] SignalR: Opening long polling request to...
- 16:37:35 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)] SignalR: longPolling timed out when
  trying to connect.
- 16:37:35 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)] SignalR: Aborted xhr request.

  (Error from subscribing to errors on the hub) SignalR error: Error: No transport could be initialized successfully. Try specifying a different transport or none at all for auto initialization.
- 16:37:35 GMT-0600(Central Standard Time)] SignalR: Stopping connection.
- 16:37:35 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)] SignalR: Fired ajax abort async =
  true.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

So there's a TransportConnectTimeout now in 2.0.0 SignalR.  It sounds like having your SQL backplane is slowing down the connect process resulting in your transports to timeout.

You can modify the TransportConnectTimeout on the server via:

```
GlobalHost.Configuration.TransportConnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
```

Therefore whenever a client tries to connect it will abide by the new timeout.

You can also modify this value on the client.  When modified the client takes it's TransportConnectTimeout and adds it to the servers and then uses the result as the timeout.  Here's how to modify the client:

```
$.connection.hub.transportConnectTimeout = 3000;
```

If the server's TransportConnectTimeout is 5s that means the client will abide by an 8s timeout window when trying to connect.

You can choose to modify one of the values, or both of the values, it doesn't matter, whatever fits your needs!

Hope this helps!

Comment: I updated both and ultimately stopped around 50 seconds with the long polling connection request still timing out. 50 seconds seems like a long time, I don't think the database is that slow, especially since the server shouldn't be to many hops away(it's a dev environment), I will have to profile it though and get back to you on that, any other suggestions? Does SignalR 2 require Web Api 2? Could that be my problem?

Comment: Nope SignalR doesn't require Web Api 2.  I'd verify that something else isn't erroring.  Try enabling detailed errors: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#handleerrors

Comment: So I profiled the database, and it definitely isn't the database. It appears to degrade after a while, On initial connection everything works as expected, however after several reconnects, it becomes unresponsive and slow. Looking into getting traces from SignalR, I will probably log a bug, if I am unable to resolve this issue.

Comment: Sorry, The errors up above are from the client with detailed errors enabled. I rolled the version back to signalr 1, and I don't get the connection protocol issues any more, but pushing messages from the server to the client through long polling takes an upwards of a minute in most cases. Does signalr 1 support tracing?